# How to go to my app home page, after authenticate users via REST API?

Tags: javascript, onelogin

I need to do SSO for swift application, which I have added in my account. We should not show ***One login's*** login screen to users.
So I authenticated via the following REST APIs.

1. To get the access token,
   https://api.us.onelogin.com/auth/oauth2/token
2. Then to get the session id,
   https://subdomain.onelogin.com/api/1/login/auth

I am getting the session id successfully. Then I redirect to a view page, where I have a JS CORS request.
This is my JS code.

```
function makeCors() {
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.withCredentials = true;
   method = "POST";
   var url = "https://subdomain.onelogin.com/session_via_api_token";
   xhr.open(method, url, true);
   xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
   body = {"session_token": "{{$session}}"};
   xhr.send(JSON.stringify(body));
   window.location.href = 'https://subdomain.onelogin.com/trust/saml2/http-post/sso/3b47ccb6-7932-4a20-8f16-ed03f03841b7';
};
```

I am getting 200 response from the session_via_api_token API.
Then I redirect user to my SSO url. But this is again taking me to login screen.

I am stuck with this. I need the user to bypass login page and go to my app page directly.
Please help me on this.

Comment: Check if you have a session id somewhere stored, if not: perform login and store the session id.

Comment: @Marc I am getting session id, once I hit the https://subdomain.onelogin.com/api/1/login/auth API. I just wanted to bypass the onelogin login page, after successfully got the session id.